# Can someone help me ID this insignia?

Tags: united-states, military, 19th-century, uniform

Charles Miller - fought with US Army at battle at Wounded Knee - this photographer took images during and after the Battle.  Anyone recognize the insignia?  He later became a Mason?  Could it be from that organization?

[image]/nWTkY.jpg

Comment: FYI: Most [Masonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freemasonry) Jewelry will feature one or more of: a carpenter's square; compasses/dividers; and the letter 'G'. However jewelry for associated organization such as [Shriners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shriners), [York Rite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/York_Rite) and [Scottish Rite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_Rite) will employ additional symbolism.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not Masonic - it's the U.S. Army [**Marksman Button**](http://www.emersoninsignia.net/files/Download/4buttons.pdf) from the 1880's.
[image]

FYI:
Most [Masonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freemasonry) Jewelry will feature one or more of: a carpenter's square; compasses/dividers; and the letter 'G'. However jewelry for associated organization such as [Shriners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shriners), [York Rite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/York_Rite) and [Scottish Rite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_Rite) will employ additional symbolism.

Comment: Thank you - I found other marksman insignia - just not this square one!  It certainly fits with his service and confirms my id of the photo!

Comment: @MollyShannon: My pleasure - The little green check mark is the accepted way to express your thanks.